# haskell `hdbc` ODBC connection gets disposed of immediately for remote MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, haskell, odbc, hdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database and run an SQL query using [`hdbc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC) and [`hdbc-odbc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-odbc-2.2.3.0)

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  mysqlSettings <- readMySQLSettings
  putStr "Connecting to MySQL database..."
  mysqlConn <- connectODBC $ buildMySQLConnectionString mysqlSettings
  putStrLn "Connected"
  _ <- run mysqlConn "USE np" []
  putStrLn " Done."
```

The database connects fine but subsequently when it runs an SQL query (`_ <- run mysqlConn "USE np" []`) I get the following error.

```hs
SqlError {seState = "", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "Tried to use a disposed ODBC Connection handle"}
```

To my understanding it seems like the error says that the connection gets immediately freed as soon as it's created. This problem only happens when connecting to a remote database (Amazon RDS in this case) and does not for my local MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is in the `cpp-options` I added blindly to the `cabal` file.

```
    ...
   
    cpp-options: -DDCABAL_BUILD_DEVELOPER

    build-depends:
        base >=4.14.2.0
        ...
```

I have no idea what `DDCABAL_BUILD_DEVELOPER` is used for. Disabling the `cpp-options` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this happens when you're using an ODBC driver which internally uses `libmysqlclient`. The thing is, `libmysqlclient` doesn't restart system calls interrupted by signals, and GHC runtime uses signals internally.

You can see how you can avoid this by looking at [`Database.HDBC.MySQL.withRTSSignalsBlocked`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-mysql-0.7.1.0/docs/Database-HDBC-MySQL.html#v:withRTSSignalsBlocked). Simply put, this function blocks `SIGALRM` and `SIGVTALRM` which are used by GHC runtime while executing your code block. You may directly use this function, or you can just copy it if you don't want to depend on `HDBC-mysql`.